# How call a Loader from a button click?

Tags: android, loader

I use the Loader to load data from my database...
When my activity start... the loader call the asynctask correctly...
but I don't know how to load data just when I click on a button!

if "onCreateLoader", called automatically when activity start, how avoid that?

**Solved:**
Using FragmentActivity...
used forceload() because the loadInBackgroung didn't work!
used getSupportLoaderManager() because getLoaderManager() didn't work too
both because supposedly the library gives problems!
but... I don't know... I'm not convinced, but...
for now, it works! :P

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button:           

        if(getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0) == null){
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
        }else{
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
        }
        break;

    case R.id.another:
        Toast.makeText(this, "another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: call `forceLoad()` on an instance of your `Loader`

Comment: but onCreateLoader will return myAsyncTaskLoader(), and I can't figure out how call myAsyncTaskLoader(), only if I click a button.

Comment: This didn't work for me, `onContentChanged()` instead of `forceLoad()` neither.  What worked for me was this: `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MyActivity.this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply call [restartLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader(int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E)) when clicking button :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(YOUR_LOADER_ID, null, mYourLoaderCallbacks);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kiruwka but how avoid start the AsyncTask on onCreateLoader? new asynctask(getActivity())

Comment: You don't need asyncTask if you already have a loader. Your loader's `loadInBackground` will be run asynchronously by default.

Comment: When I apply a Loader I implement onCreateLoader, onLoadFinished and onLoaderReset... but loadInBackground inside a loader... I didn't knew that I cant! (I'm newbie)

Comment: In your `onCreateLoader` you return newly constructed custom Loader (I assume subclass of `AsyncTaskLoader`). That custom Loader class should have  `loadInBackground` method, that will be called in a separate thread by Android for you. You can refer to example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

Comment: I'm using a custom loader (now I know how it call), but, when my activity start, onCreateLoader call my AsyncTaskLoader is called and... I need call it just when click on button! :)

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803865/android-loader-vs-asynctask-on-button-tap that's what I need, but this class: "AsyncTaskLoaderResult<E>", I don't understand :S

Comment: This is too complex. You can just use AsyncTaskLoader<Result>, where Result is what you return from `loadInBackground`. You can see the proper way of doing it in the link I provided. Hope that helps

Comment: mmm ... that link does not exist LoaderCallbacks. So ... can I use without LoaderCallbacks AsyncTaskLoader? (I did not know that)

Comment: In that example Activity is a `LoaderCallbacks`. Just search `onCreateLoader` and see how it is implemented. And no, you can not use loader without `Callbacks`

Comment: Thanks but... I used LoaderCallbacks with AsyncTaskLoader to Load json data on a ListFragment. but now I need execute the AsyncTaskLoader only when I press a button, and not when it is called in onCreateLoader.

Comment: loader is started when you call `initLoader` or `restartLoader`. Just don't call `initLoader` in places when you don't want your loader to fire.

Comment: mmm... so, instead putting initloader inside of onActivityCreated, Can I place it only in the "onClick"?